# Service OnFailure trigerred only after burst limit reached

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-unit

I'm using a systemd unit file in order to control a python process running on a server (with systemd v247).

This process must be restarted 60 seconds after it exits, either on failure or on success, except if it fails 5 times in 600 seconds.

This unit file links another service in order to notify failures by email.

`/etc/systemd/system/python-test.service`

```ini
[Unit]
After=network.target
OnFailure=mailer@%n.service

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/home/debian/tmp.py

# Any exit status different than 0 is considered as an error
SuccessExitStatus=0

StandardOutput=append:/var/log/python-test.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/python-test.log

# Always restart service 60sec after exit
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

# Stop restarting service after 5 consecutive fail in 600sec interval
StartLimitInterval=600
StartLimitBurst=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/systemd/system/mailer@.service`

```ini
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/home/debian/mailer.py --to "admin.mail@gmail.com" --subject "Systemd service %I failed" --message "A systemd service failed %I on %H"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The triggering of `OnFailure` worked pretty well during basic testing. However when I added the following section into the Unit file, the `OnFailure` only triggered once the 5 consecutive fails occurred.

```ini
StartLimitInterval=600
StartLimitBurst=5
```

This is not the behavior I would like, since I want be be notified everytime the process fails, even if the burst limit is not reached yet.

---

When checking process status, the output is not the same when burst limit is not reached

```
● python-test.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python-test.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-22 19:51:23 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 1421600 ExecStart=/home/debian/tmp.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1421600 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 31ms

Dec 22 19:51:23 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Than when it is

```
● python-test.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python-test.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-22 19:52:02 UTC; 24s ago
    Process: 1421609 ExecStart=/home/debian/tmp.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1421609 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 31ms

Dec 22 19:51:56 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: Stopped python-test.service.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: Failed to start python-test.service.
Dec 22 19:52:02 test-vps systemd[1]: python-test.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

I couldn't find anything explaining how to modify the triggering of `OnFailure` within the unit file.

Is there a way to notify mails everytime the process fails and still keep the burst limit ?

Comment: About comment line: *"Stop restarting service after 5 consecutive fail"*, using `StartLimitInterval` and `StartLimitBurst` don't care about if the unit exit successfully or with some error, so If the unit exit successfully **5 times consecutive** then the service `python-test.service` will stop  restarting. However, according to your unit configuration the service will result in an error because of the `Start request repeated too quickly.` and then stops forever.

Comment: And from `man systemd.unit`: *"OnFailure=A space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when this unit enters the "failed" state. A service unit using Restart= enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached"*. Thus using what you have is not useful here, you have to use another systemd unit options

Comment: Just to be sure (so I can provide a possible solution), what you want is to execute the `mailer@.service` systemd service only when `python-test.service` exit with some error (in this case the exit status is determined by `/home/debian/tmp.py`)? And also you want to stop restarting the service only **after 5 consecutive fails in 600sec interval**?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Thanks for the information. That's exactly what I want to do, I want to execute the `mailer@.service` when the `python-test.service` fails (any exit code different than 0) and additionally stop relaunching if it fails 5 time in a 600 seconds interval. Otherwise the service must always be restarted.

Comment: (just for clarification) Does it have to be **5 consecutive fails** in that interval ? Or does it not matter if the fails are consecutive?

Comment: It has to be 5 consecutive fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you should do in order to work with the system service as you want (changes are on **/etc/systemd/system/python-test.service**).

1. Change `Restart=always` to `Restart=on-failure`
2. The values `StartLimitInterval=600`, `StartLimitBurst=5` seem to be supported yet. However you should place them in `[Unit]`. If you place `StartLimitInterval` in `[Unit]` you can rename it to `StartLimitIntervalSec` (`man systemd.unit` uses `StartLimitIntervalSec` instead).
3. Add `RemainAfterExit=no` in `[Service]` section.
4. Add this line in `[Service]` section: `TimeoutStopSec=infinity`
5. Use the environment variable `EXIT_STATUS` in the script to determine if the script exited successfully or not.
6. Change `OnFailure=mailer@%n.service` to `OnFailure=mailer@%N.service`. The difference between both is that using `%N` will remove the suffix.
7. Install and start the service `atd` (`sudo systemctl start atd.service`) to be able to use `at` command. Or if you do not want to use `at` then you can write another systemd service to relaunch the service. (in this example, I used `relaunch.service`)
8. Use the same values on `sleep` and `RestartSec`. In your case, since `RestartSec` has `60` then in this line the sleep must have `60` too:

```bash
 echo "sleep 60; sudo systemctl start ${1}.service" | at now
```

9. Using `ExecStart` and `ExecStopPost=` for getting the *ExitStatus* of your main process: `/home/debian/tmp.py`. Don't use `ExecStop` ,from `man systemd.service`:

> ExecStop=
>
> > Note that the commands specified in ExecStop= are only executed when the service started successfully first. They are not invoked if the service was
> > never started at all, or in case its start-up failed, for example because any of the commands specified in ExecStart=, ExecStartPre= or ExecStartPost=
> > failed (and weren't prefixed with "-", see above) or timed out. Use ExecStopPost= to invoke commands when a service failed to start up correctly and is
> > shut down again.

---

The service **/etc/systemd/system/python-test.service** should be:

```ini
[Unit]
After=network.target
OnFailure=mailer@%N.service

StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=600
 
[Service]  
Type=simple 
TimeoutStopSec=infinity
ExecStart=/home/debian/tmp.py
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c 'echo The Service  has exited with values: $$EXIT_STATUS,$$SERVICE_RESULT,$$EXIT_CODE'
ExecStopPost=/home/debian/bin/checkSuccess "%N"
# Any exit status different than 0 is considered as an error
SuccessExitStatus=0
StandardOutput=append:/tmp/python-out-test.log
StandardError=append:/tmp/python-err-test.log
# Always restart service 60sec after exit
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
RemainAfterExit=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

And **/home/debian/bin/checkSuccess** should have this:

**Solution 1:** Using `at` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EXIT_STATUS" -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "sleep 60; sudo systemctl start ${1}.service" | at now
   exit 0
else
   systemctl start "mailer@${1}.service"
   exit 0
fi
```

**Solution 2:** Using another systemd service:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EXIT_STATUS" -eq 0 ]
then
   systemctl start relaunch.service
else
   systemctl start "mailer@${1}.service"
fi
exit 0
```

And the `relaunch.service` should have:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Relaunch Python Test Service

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=no 
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo Delay; sleep 10 ; systemctl start python-test.service'
```

The `"$EXIT_STATUS"` variable which is set by the systemd service is determined by the exit status of `/home/debian/tmp.py`.

The `${1}` represents the name of the unit:  `python-test` and it's passed to script in the line `/home/debian/bin/checkSuccess "%N"`.

---

**Notes:**

1. You can check the logs: `'echo The Service %n has exited with values: $$EXIT_STATUS,$$SERVICE_RESULT,$$EXIT_CODE'`  in real time  by using:

```bash
tail -f /tmp/python-out-test.log
```

2. If you use the solution 2 ( with `relaunch.service` ) when you want to stop your main service you should run:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop relaunch.service
#Might not be necessary but you stop python service too:
# sudo systemctl stop python-test.service
```

Comment: I does work perfectly, I would have though that systemd could handle this case natively but using `at` does the work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Arkaik I had used systemd `Timers` but that was causing problems. So I had to use the `at` command. Using `cron` jobs should be useful here too. About why did I use this is because I cannot stop, start, restart the unit *inside the same* unit (the unit python test runs checkSuccess which restarts this one). I tried using `exec` as well as `&` and that did not work. Maybe using Type=forking should be useful to avoid using `at` but with forking I was unable to get the exit status (I'll have to read the systemd manual to know why happenes this).

Comment: I may try with another solution just by curiosity later but for now on it does work well using `at` and it's quite simple to understand and to track so I think I'll keep that solution. If I find something else that's also working, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @Arkaik Same for me, I'll try by using `Type=forking` and other shell scripts. If it works then I'll post another answer.

Comment: @Arkaik updated answer by using another systemd service instead of `at`. It seems to work correctly:)